# Im having trouble adding the bluetooth feature to my expo app, how can i fix it?

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth, expo, android-bluetooth

Hi guys how are you? Im trying to add communication with a esp to my expo app and i cant find the way to do it. I tried every tutorial but i cant find the way. the link to my repo: (https://github.com/cesarcerbino/Bluetoothexpo)

I tried several youtube tutorials on how to make the ble library but i cant make it work for some reason.  ive used a lot of bluetooth librarys and im not familliar with the react native cli, ive read that its easyer but my project is all based in expo cli.